# How are gyroscopes used for motion control?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque, robotics

Is there a way to use gyroscopes to control the motion of a pen-like device? I am trying to build a device that will be able to take in a radius input and draw shapes without physically moving my hand in the shape of the shape. An example of this type of device would be the spyro-gyro toy pen.

Comment: What do you mean by "take in" as in  take in a radius input? You can re-purpose a 3d printer to 2d with a pen and voila ... avoiding gyroscopes. For gyroscopes investigate some automatic flight control mechanisms etc.

Comment: voting to close as to vague to make any sense

Comment: @agentp: Not really. The answer is a plain 'no', no control moment gyroscopes of such size and sufficient torque. Readout would be doable, but not "replay". The unclear details like input of radius of drawn circle are moot, as without actuators that could move it while held in hand no matter how the inputs work there will be no output.

Answer (score 1):

"Control" as in "monitor" or "drive"?

Gyroscopes can monitor motion of a pen-like device - gyroscopic sensors on chip are available and small enough to fit in one. I don't think you could drive motion of one though - that requires considerable torque, actuators in multiple axis, and a flywheel of mass no less than two orders of magnitude the mass of what is driven.

An example of gyroscopes driving motion of an object, you can take International Space Station's [CMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_moment_gyroscope)s. ISS has several of these, they weigh something of order of a ton each, and they take a couple hours to turn the station.

AFAIK there are no pen-sized CMGs in production, building one on your own, due to miniaturization required is out of reach of anyone without access to micromechanics workshop, and even then they only control angle - rotation, not translation, so your pen tip could draw nice circles in the air, but as soon as you push it to paper, with just rotation and no translation control the best you can get is an ellipse.

Comment: Control as in drive. My plan was to manipulate the angle of the flywheel of a standard gyroscope to generate a torque that can produce variable circular motion, and then to use gears to magnify the torque to the pen tip. In essence, to magnify the abilites of a small CMG. However, due to the concerns that you mentioned, I am no longer sure if this is feasible.

Comment: @RyanAlli: It is not feasible - no fundamental physics reason, just plain engineering - micromechanisms of this scale and this torque are beyond current capabilities of engineering. Reaction wheel based controllers of some 5x5x5cm exist (3 flywheels in 3 axis, their speed controlled) capable of "walking" over a table surface, and even smaller of minuscule torque for use in cubesats, but there is no active gimbal this tiny that could create the torque required.

Comment: Would a flywheel about an inch across work? I assume that is what makes the spyro gyro pen work.

Comment: @RyanAlli: It's not so much about the flywheel as about controlling its orientation. You can spin the flywheel up, and it will create some torque when you try to turn it - but doing something useful with that torque is a different matter.